# Read data from Informix Database. Having folder app.dbs with *.IDX, *.Dat files

Tags: informix

I have a friend who has a management application, and he would like to import some of his data in Excel.

The thing is I have no idea about how to read this type of files,

In his application directory he has a folder named app.dbs. Inside there are *.idx and *.dat files.

What would be the easiest way to read this files? Maybe ODBC connector, or installing some version of Informix DB??

Comment: try cobol data viewer 
http://www.cobolproducts.com/datafile/data-viewer.html

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like C-ISAM files, or an Informix-SE (Standard Engine) install. You most certainly can't read them directly. Googling [Informix C-ISAM files ODBC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=informix%20c-isam%20files%20odbc) generates plenty of results. Also [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Informix_C-ISAM) explains the relationship between the two.

I've never used SE, but assuming its installation is reasonably similar to its big brother Informix Dynamic Server (and I believe it is), have a look on your friend's computer for an 'Informix' directory. You may find an `%INFORMIXDIR%` environment variable to point you in the right direction. Within that, look for an executable in its subdirectory `bin` called `dbaccess.exe`. Run that from a DOS prompt and you should hopefully get an SQL interpreter that allows you to read and extract the data.

If you have no luck finding such a directory, then it's more than likely the "management application" is writing C-ISAM directly, and you'll need an ODBC driver for C-ISAM, as you surmised.

Answer (score 0):

The name `app.dbs` containing the `.dat` and `.idx` files is an almost sure indication that you have an Informix SE (Standard Engine) database (someone might have faked it, but it is pretty improbable).

Given that you may be able to use an Informix ODBC driver and SE itself to access the database, or you may be able to use an ISAM-based ODBC driver to access the database.  It depends in part on whether this is a one-time migration or an ongoing access while the application continues to work on the database.

Assuming all of this is installed on Windows, you should indeed find a %INFORMIXDIR% directory, which will have a `dbaccess.exe` in the `bin` sub-directory, and an `sqlexec.exe` either in the `bin` directory or in the `lib` directory (it would be in `$INFORMIXDIR/lib` on Unix; I'm not sure about Windows).  These should be able to access the database.  If you find `sqlexec` but not `dbaccess`, then you've got a seriously old version (more than 20 years old, but I know of other people still using such archaic versions).  You should be able to identify the version by running `dbaccess -V` or `sqlexec -V`.  If it is 7.25, it is reasonably recent (that's been current for a decade or more); if it is older than that, it is verging on the archaic.