# What is the Informix database file extension

Tags: database, unix

I've got an image file of a hard drive from a client that wants a database extracted out of it. The client does not know any details except that the database was once installed on the server from which the image was created.

I found out that it is a UNIX system with a Informix DBS installed, but I am unable to find any database files. I'm not sure about the version of Informix, but it seem that it was installed around 15 years ago.

I'm not able to boot from the image. I'm just viewing the files.

Do informix database files have an extension and what could it be? Any other tips how to identify the database files?

Comment: The extension is .IDX The answer can be found here also...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562340/read-data-from-informix-database-having-folder-app-dbs-with-idx-dat-files

Comment: Thanks! Do you maybe know if that is the case for all informix versions? I'm asking because I cannot find any files with such extensions on the image I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know whether the database was Informix Standard Engine (SE) or Informix (Informix Dynamic Server — IDS — or one of its multitude of namesakes over the years)?

#### Standard Engine

If it was SE, then the database files are in a directory `database.dbs` and the files holding the indexes and data for the tables have extensions `.idx` and `.dat`.  That's pretty much fixed and very easy.  The files and the directory should belong to group `informix`; the owner will be whoever created the database or the table within the database.

#### Informix Dynamic Server

If it was IDS, then there is no guaranteed naming convention, and Informix didn't even recommend one.  Depending on the state of the disk, I'd look for large files that are owned by user `informix` and belong to group `informix` and have `660` (`-rw-rw----`) permissions.  The files will have structure, but it isn't easy to discern it.

For example, I have 'chunk 0 of the root dbspace' in a file `toru_31.rootdbs.c0` (server name `toru_31` — a naming standard I imposed on my systems).  It starts with:

```
0x0000: 00 00 00 00 01 00 AB 89 03 00 00 18 30 01 C0 06   ............0...
0x0010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 49 42 4D 20 49 6E 66 6F   ........IBM Info
0x0020: 72 6D 69 78 20 44 79 6E 61 6D 69 63 20 53 65 72   rmix Dynamic Ser
0x0030: 76 65 72 20 43 6F 70 79 72 69 67 68 74 20 32 30   ver Copyright 20
0x0040: 30 31 2C 20 32 30 31 31 20 20 49 42 4D 20 43 6F   01, 2011  IBM Co
0x0050: 72 70 6F 72 61 74 69 6F 6E 2E 00 00 00 00 00 00   rporation.......
0x0060: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 08 00 00   ................
0x0070: BA 2D CC 50 1A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C8 00 00 00   .-.P............
0x0080: 31 31 37 33 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   1173............
0x0090: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
```

However, 'chunk 1 of the root dbspace' (file `toru_31.rootdbs.c1`) starts:

```
0x0000: 00 00 00 00 02 00 F1 C6 00 00 00 18 18 00 E4 07   ................
0x0010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
* (125)
0x07F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 61 C6 92 00   ............a...
0x0800: 69 6E 66 6F 72 6D 69 78 69 6E 66 6F 72 6D 69 78   informixinformix
* (127)
0x1000: 02 00 00 00 02 00 BE B6 06 00 08 08 20 00 D8 07   ............ ...
0x1010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 06 00 00 01 00 00 00   ................
0x1020: EA 06 00 00 03 00 00 00 75 08 00 00 08 00 00 00   ........u.......
0x1030: A1 08 00 00 08 00 00 00 B5 0A 00 00 30 03 00 00   ............0...
```

There is very little information there to give the game away. Although the appearance of `informix` (128 lines containing `informix` twice) looks like a tell-tale sign, it isn't — I created the chunk with a program that writes `informix` over the disk space.  It simply shows where the server has not yet written data to this chunk.

You can look for `$INFORMIXDIR`.  In fact, if there's a directory `/INFORMIXTMP`, you can look in the text file `/INFORMIXTMP/.infxdirs` to see where Informix has been installed.  From those directories, you can look in `$INFORMIXDIR/etc` for `onconfig` files - they're text files that contain an entry `ROOTPATH`, which is the pathname of chunk 0 of the root dbspace — basically, the starting point for the whole system.  There's usually an `onconfig.std` which is a template; the naming convention is not firmly fixed, though I always use `onconfig.servername` (so the config file for `toru_31` is `onconfig.toru_31`).  You may also find other files around in `$INFORMIXDIR/etc`.  For example, there's a file `oncfg_toru_31.31` (prefix `oncfg_`, followed by server name `toru_31` followed by dot and the server number `31`) which contains information about the chunks and other disk space etc used by the server.  You might also see binary files analogous to `.conf.toru_31` and `.infos.toru_31` — the `.infos` file is normally present only while the server is up but the `.conf` file persists.  These files have some limited information in them, most notably the name of the `onconfig` file.

If you can find these files on the disk, then you can proceed to identify where the data was stored on the disk.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!